# PlayN Sound: Requested buffer too large

Tags: java, playn

I'm trying to play a sound in PlayN.

```
Sound soundtrack = assetManager().getSound("sounds/soundtrack");
```

But get this

Failed to open sound sounds/soundtrack.mp3
javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException: Failed to allocate clip data: Requested buffer too large.

What to do?

It's an mp3, 6:02 minutes long. 1.09Mb

Payload Size: 1087776 bytes
Header found at: 2264 bytes
Enc Delay: 576, Zero Padding: 824
Length: 362 seconds
MPEG-2.5 layer 3
24 kbps, 5036 frames
8000 Hz Joint Stereo

Comment: Related discussion: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=1270993

Comment: Did you ever get a complete answer to this? I'm having a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell the file size limitation (which is what you are hitting) is a limitation of the way that sound is implemented on the Java backend. The good news is that the HTML backend should play the audio fine, you just won't be able to hear it when testing the application locally using the JRE.

Comment: I tried my Java application on a Windows Seven computer with a 64bit JVM and the sounds was working. I can't confirm that it's related but it's something to try if you would like the sound on Java.